# Normalized the array struct in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explnation : how we can concate the `time` and `sv` . convert  normalizaed the array stract

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "1998-08-31T03",
        "sv": {
          "05": {
            "13": 0,
            "14": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

For example expected document will be.

```
{
 "data" : {
    "1998-08-31T03:05:13Z": 0,
    "1998-08-31T03:05:14Z": 1,
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `data` array
- `$objectToArray` convert `sv` object to key-value array
- `$map` to iterate loop of `sv` array
- `$objectToArray` convert minute object to key-value array
- `$map` to iterate loop of minutes array
- `$concat` to concat the required format of date parts
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value pair to object
- `$concatArrays` to concat `data` elements
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `data` array
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of nested `data` elements
- `$mergeObjects` to merge date objects

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $map: {
                  input: { $objectToArray: "$$this.sv" },
                  as: "s",
                  in: {
                    $map: {
                      input: { $objectToArray: "$$s.v" },
                      as: "s1",
                      in: {
                        $arrayToObject: [
                          [
                            {
                              k: {
                                $concat: ["$$this.time", ":", "$$s.k", ":", "$$s1.k", "Z"]
                              },
                              v: "$$s1.v"
                            }
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: {},
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$$this",
                  initialValue: {},
                  in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pFUlLF4B1JQ)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.sv": {
        $objectToArray: "$data.sv"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.sv"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.sv.v": {
        $objectToArray: "$data.sv.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.sv.v"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data": {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              k: {
                $concat: [
                  "$data.time",
                  ":",
                  "$data.sv.k",
                  ":",
                  "$data.sv.v.k",
                  "Z"
                ]
              },
              v: "$data.sv.v.v"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $mergeObjects: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fuogWURPKk4)